# numpy select all elements from under array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an np.array with 3 dimension. I just want to select all n-th element from the last array.

I know that I can select it like

```
array[:, :, 0]
```

But I need to use a function, is there any numpy function to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by you needing to use a function? What part is variable?

Comment: I'm not using numpy through python I just play with PythonObject so I can't use [] like in python but I can call Python function so if I can select with a function that would help me

Comment: You create a function which takes a numpy array as input and returns the required element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[]` operator calls `__getitem__` on the object it was used on. In your case, it would be the equivalent of calling

```py
array.__getitem__((slice(None), slice(None), 0))
```

This is because `[:]` is an empty slice (i.e. `slice(None)`), and you are calling the `[]` operator with 3 value, which is equivalent to calling `__getitem__` with a tuple of 3 values.

Comment: It's exactly what I was searching ! instead of using [] I needed to use a function

Comment: Well, fair play, I didn't see this being the answer but you've clearly seen the question in a different way to me.

Comment: @roganjosh They're interfacing with Numpy/Python from another language (as evident by their comment on the question), and so they can't use Python syntax to access elements in their array. They were looking for a function they could call in-place of the Python `[]` operator.

Comment: That makes sense. You've already got my upvote but I wouldn't have snagged this approach from what was said tbh so thanks for pointing it out :)